# Linear transformation of random variable to get correlation 0

Tags: statistics, random-variables, covariance

Given a set of normally distributed random variables $_ ( = 1,2, ⋯ , )$ with covariance matrix  = $_{}$ , assuming all the $_ ( = 1,2, ⋯ , )$ have 0 mean.

Please outline an algorithm to transform $_ ,  = 1,2, ⋯ ,  $ into a new set of random variables 
$_ ( = 1,2, ⋯ , )$ using linear transformation, i.e, please find coefficients ${} such that

$$ =  \sum_{i=1}^n _{}_{}   ,= 1 , 2 , ⋯ $$
Where $_$ and $_$ have 0 correlation for every$ , = 1,2,⋯,  ≠ $.

Assume n=2

$$c_{ij}=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        Cov(X_1,X_1) & Cov(X_1,X_2)  \\
        Cov(X_2, X_1) & Cov(X_2,X_2)  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$Y_1=b_{11}X_1+b_{21}X_2$$
$$ Y_2=b_{12}X_1+b_{22}X_2$$

Since Correlation=$\frac{Cov}{{\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y}}$,then try to get Cov=0.

By the linear relationship,

$$Cov(Y_1,Y_2)=Cov(b_{11}X_1,b_{12}X_1)+Cov(b_{11}X_1,b_{22}X_2)+Cov(b_{21}X_2,b_{12}X_2)+Cov(b_{21}X_2,b_{22}X_2)$$

$$Cov(Y_1,Y_2)=b_{11}b_{12}Cov(X_1,X_1)+b_{11}b_{22}Cov(X_1,X_2)+b_{21}b_{12}Cov(X_2,X_2)+b_{21}b_{22}Cov(X_2,X_2)$$

Try to diagonalize the Covariance Matrix，

$$\begin{pmatrix}
        a & b  \\
        c & d  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
        \begin{pmatrix}
        Cov(X_1,X_1) & Cov(X_1,X_2)  \\
        Cov(X_2, X_1) & Cov(X_2,X_2)  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
        e & f  \\
        g & h  \\
        \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0  \\
        0 & 1  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Then, $$ecCov(X_1,X_1)+edCov(X_2,X_1)+gcCov(X_1,X_2)+gdCov(X_2,X_2)=0$$
the corresponding coefficient is $$b_{11}=e,b_{12}=c,b_{21}=g,b_{22}=d$$

Comment: (HInt) Try diagonalizing the matrix.

Comment: How can you explain more, why should I diagonalize?

Comment: Ill counter with another question: What are the correlations if the covariance matrix is diagonal?

Comment: I rethink about it and can you tell me whether it is correct?

Comment: .C is the covariance matrix Matrix $LCL^{-1}=I$ Considering the multiplication of the left three matrix to get the entry 0 on the right side, its coefficents correspond to the $b_{11},b_{12},b_{22}$...that can make the covariance of the new random variable to be 0.

Comment: So the algorithm is to find the matrix L first and then write out $Cov(Y_1,Y_2) $ using $Cov(X_1,X_2),Cov(X_2,X_3),Cov(X_1,X_3)$ and the coefficients is then correspond to the entries.